# How to select field values and insert them in another table with for loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I want to write a function in Postgres which select a column from table A then loop through the values and insert them to table B.

Here is what I have so far:

```
declare 
    aid integer
begin
    for aid in select a_id from table_a
    loop
        insert into table_b (a_id)
            values (aid)
    end loop;
end;
```

However, I got syntax error at line `for aid in select a_id from table_a`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop - just an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (a_id)
SELECT a_id FROM table_a
```

Comment: what if there is another field I need to insert to table_b together with a_id which would be argument of the function?

Comment: @ddd just select it as a literal

Comment: but whatever that `select` returns is an array of integer, while the other variable to be inserted is a single value. How does it work to insert an array and integer at the same time to two integer fields?

Comment: @ddd this comment is completely unclear. Please edit your question with the actual usecase you're trying to solve